# How to find references when refactoring rails application with textmate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, tdd, textmate

I have been practicing TDD in C# for several years now and recently have moved to Ruby on Rails full time. I am continuing the practice of TDD with RSpec. My question is regarding the process of finding references while refactoring. In Visual Studio I was addicted to Resharper's "find all references" when renaming or replacing methods.

How do test driven practitioners in ruby find references to methods when replacing/renaming/etc?

I realize because ruby is a dynamic language a "find all references" IDE function would not  work, so any I am looking for a shift in thinking as much as a simple solution.

Thanks 
- Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing a "Search in Project"? (Cmd+Shift+F). It allows you to search and replace, with regexp support and works, and should work just how you need (if I recall correctly how Resharper used to work).

It can get kinda slow with big projects, though, so be sure to checkout both [Awk in Project](http://github.com/protocool/ack-tmbundle/tree/master) or [Grep in Project](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/06/grep-in-project-command-for-textmate) (although -at least for the last one- not sure if they deal only with searching)

Comment: That works as long as the method name is unique throughout the project, which doesn't seem to happen that much.